# DMZ passthru script

Tags: php, http, curl

I have a server that cannot be connected to from the internet, but I need to get some info to it. I have another server that can, so I have a simple passthru script that I want to see if you all think is secure.

Basically, you hit [this](http://example.com/domain=subdomain1&url=it/myscript.php) and if it is in the white list, it returns everything, including keeping the proper headers for Content-Type.

```
<?php

$domain = ( $_REQUEST['domain'] ?: '' ); 
$url    = $_REQUEST['url'];

/** set up whitelists */
$domain_whitelist = array(
    '',
    'subdomain1',
    'subdomain2',
    'subdomain3'
);

$url_whitelist = array(
    'it/myscript.php',
    'scripts/add.php',
    'scripts/member.php',
    'scripts/status_update.php'
);

/** check REQUEST against whitelists */
if(!in_array($domain, $domain_whitelist))
    diemail('Invalid domain. An email has been sent to the administrator.');

if(!in_array($url, $url_whitelist))
    diemail('Invalid url. An email has been sent to the administrator.');

/** append dot to subdomain */
$domain .= ( $domain != '' ? '.' : '');

/** set up curl call */
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://{$domain}example.com/{$url}" );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $_POST);

/** execute curl */
$response = curl_exec($ch);

/** handle curl response */
if($response === FALSE )
{
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
else{ 
    $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
    $header_str = substr($response, 0, $header_size);
    $body = substr($response, $header_size);

    $headers = explode("\n",$header_str);

    /** rebuild header */
    foreach($headers as $header){
        if( strpos($header,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE ){ 
            header($header);
        }
    }
    /** passthru data */
    echo $body;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks nice, but it could be improved upon:

1. `$domain != '' ? '.' : ''`; With ternaries in PHP, if you don't need one of two results, you can reverse the if condition and use `?:`.

   ```
   $domain == '' ?: '.'
   ```
2. You should make sure you leave whitespace before and after your binary operators and in particular, your comma in `explode("\n",$header_str)`, but don't add extra whitespace in your `if-else` statement, between the brackets.
3. If you're interested in ternaries, you can condense the following into a ternary by reversing the condition and using `?:`:

> ```
> if(strpos($header,'Content-Type:') !== FALSE){ 
>     header($header);
> }
> ```

into: `strpos($header,'Content-Type:') === FALSE ?: header($header);`

4. Your comments are formatted incorrectly:

`/** passthru data */` should be `// Pass through data`, and you shouldn't use `/* */` for single line comments, and you even have an superfluous `*` after `/*`.

`/* */` is for multiline comments, and only then would you use a `*` per line.